# Ideal gas number of microstates constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

while applying the equation $\Omega(E)=BV^N E^{3N/2}$ for a system with ideal gas in two boxes separated by a divider, I was asked to calculate the change in entropy after removing the divider. 
The final result was $\Delta S=K_Bln(\frac{32}{B})$. How can I find B to show that the change in entropy is not negative? 
starting parameters are: 
$N_1=N_2=N$ 
 $V_1=V_2=V$ 
 $T_1=T_2=T$ 
my calculations went as such: 
$\Delta S=S_f - S_i = K_B ln(B(2V)^{2N} (2E)^{2\frac{3N}{2}} - [K_Bln(BV^N E^\frac{3N}{2})+K_Bln(BV^NE^\frac{3N}{2})]=K_Bln(\frac{32BV^{2N}E^{3N}}{B^2 V^{2N}E^{3N}})=K_Bln(\frac{32}{B})$

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: ... but more importantly, if you do not define $B$, this doesn't really have any good chances of being answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You final result is not correct:

\begin{align}
\Delta S & = S_f - S_i\\
 &= K_B\, ln\left\{B(2V)^{2N} (2E)^{2\frac{3N}{2}}\right\} - \left[K_Bln\left(BV^N E^\frac{3N}{2}\right)+K_Bln\left(BV^NE^\frac{3N}{2}\right)\right]\\
&=K_B\,ln\left(\frac{2^{5N}BV^{2N}E^{3N}}{B^2 V^{2N}E^{3N}}\right)\\
&=K_B\,ln\left(\frac{2^{5N}}{B}\right)\\
&=K_B\,ln\left(\frac{32^{N}}{B}\right)
\end{align}